# How to format a date like "5 min", "1 hour,", "Yesterday", "1 Week ago"?

Tags: swift3, xcode6, nsdate

I am trying to get something similar to facebook post date/time. Like 1 min, 1 hour, Yesterday, Week ago etc.

This is the is function I am using to get this format: (`Oct-22 17:28 PM`)

```
func convertTime(serverTime: Double)  -> String {
    let serverTime = serverTime
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: serverTime)
    let dateFomatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFomatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd HH:mm a"
    let strDate = dateFomatter.string(from: date)
    print("This is the post's date: \(strDate)")

    return strDate
}
```

Comment: read the `DateFormatter` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting), please...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
let before = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-10-23 10:28:17")!

//getting the current time
let now = Date()

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropAll
formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1 
formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .weekOfMonth, .day, .hour, .minute]
formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true 


let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ ago", comment: "e.g. '2 hours ago'")

let timeString = formatter.string(from: before, to: now)
```

Comment: thank you very much, your solution worked for me. Just have to change the "before" to my server time. Now I am getting the time like this:
The time is  About 5 days 
The time is  About 21 hours
The time is  About 3 minutes
The time is  About 3 minutes

Comment: You can get rid of the 'About' by setting `formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = false`