# How I can get specific date format?

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I try make rss reader and I get date in format like this  2019-08-15 13:10:13 +0000 but I want show my date in format like -> Just recently, Today, Yesterday and Fri, Jul 31, 2019 etc. I know how I can make one format for all day from date formatter, but how I can get different format?

```
extension Formatter {

    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        return formatter
    }()

}

extension Date {

    var iso8601: String {
        return Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self)
    }

   static let dayMonthYearTimeDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm" 2018, 12:30"
        return dateFormatter
    }()

}
```

Comment: See this has helpfull answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882367/how-to-format-a-date-like-5-min-1-hour-yesterday-1-week-ago

Comment: Why you don't use the library SwiftDate?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t share your model so I will make an assumption that your “news” item for the RSS reader is something akin to:

```
struct NewsItem {
    let date: Date
}
```

where `date` is the date the news item was published.

You might consider creating and utilizing a `Calendar` object as it was designed to conduct calendrical calculations. For instance

```
let calendar = formatter.calendar
let newsItem = // ...some previously initialized NewsItem

if calendar.isDateInYesterday(newsItem.date) == true {
    // ...code to appropriately assign a string “Yesterday” to wherever you’d like
}
```